# Core Data: awakeFromFetch Not Getting Called For Unsaved Contexts

Tags: core-data

First, let me illustrate the steps to reproduce the 'bug'.

1. Create a new NSManagedObject.
2. Fault the managed object using refreshObject:mergeChanges:NO - At this time, the didTurnIntoFault notification is received by the object.
3. 'Unfault' the object again by using willAccessValueForKey:nil - At this time, the awakeFromFetch notification is supposed to be received BUT NO NOTIFICATION COMES. All code relying of it firing fails, and the bread in the toaster burns :)

The interesting thing is that if I 'save' the managed object context before performing step 2, everything works okay and the awakeFromFetch notification comes as expected.

Currently the workaround that I am using is 'saving' the context at regular intervals, but that is more of a hack since we actually need to save the context once (when the application terminates).

Googling has so far returned nothing concrete, except a gentleman [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/cocoa-dev@lists.apple.com/msg30115.html) that seems to have run into the same problem.

So my question is twofold - Is this really a bug, and if it is, then what other walkarounds (sic) do you suggest.

EDIT: THIS IS NOT A BUG BUT THAT WAS JUST ME BEING STUPID. See, if I turn an object to fault without saving it, then there is no history of the object to maintain. So in this case (i.e for an unsaved object) there is no logical concept of awakeFromFetch (since it was never saved). Please do let me know if I am still getting it all mixed up.

Anyways, turns out my 'actual' problem was somewhere else - hidden well behind 2 gotcha's

1. If you use refreshObject:mergeChanges:NO to turn an object to fault in order to break any  retain cycles that core data might have established, you have to do the same for the child objects also - Each child object which might have gotten involved in a cyclic retain with someone else will have to be manually faulted. What I had (wrongly) assumed was that faulting the parent will automatically break the cycles amongst the children.
2. The reverseTransform function of your custom transformers will NOT be called when such a object (i.e. which has been forcefully faulted) is resurrected by firing a fault on it. This in my eyes IS a bug, since there is no other way for me to know when the object is alive again. Anyways, the workaround in this case was to set the staleness interval to an arbitrarily low value so that core data skips its cache and always calls the reverseTransform function to resurrect the object. Better suggestions are welcome.

it really has been one of those days :)

Comment: Can you create an answer rather than embedding it in your question?